# How does a client pick a NS server out of multiple possibilities?

Tags: domain-name-system, nslookup

When a client attempts a DNS resolution, let's say for `google.com`, often multiple NS servers are returned, like:

```
ns2.google.com.
ns1.google.com.
ns3.google.com.
ns4.google.com.
```

How does a client pick one of these?

From my observations it seems to be random, but is this the default behavior (maybe as defined by some RFC)? Or does every implementation do it differently? And if so, what is the most used algorithm?

Comment: That's system and configuration dependent. It may choose one at random. It may query all of them and then use whichever answer arrived first (dnsmasq has this feature).

Comment: thanks @NikitaKipriyanov . Do you know if that is considered somewhat standard behavior or is really every client implementation different?